# JKS not found - No such algorithm: JKS for provider BC - [Linux, Tomcat]

Tags: java, algorithm, tomcat, ssl, jks

I'm having trouble setting up SSL authentication with Hermes(corvus)/Tomcat, when initialising the server's "ssl-key-manager" inside one of the corvus config files i'm getting the following error

'no such algorithm: JKS for provider BC'

I have looked everywhere for a solution! Here are a few of the things i've already tried, any help would be greatly appreciated.

- I have copied the 'bcprov-jdk15.jar' to the /jre/lib/ext/ folder
- I have registered the bouncyCastle provider in the java.security file
  with '
  security.provider.9=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider'
- I have tried changing the store type from JKS to PKCS12 and using my
  private key directly (this just gives me a certificate chain error)

My setup looks like this

```
<component id="ssl-key-manager" name="SSL Key Manager">
        <class>hk.hku.cecid.piazza.commons.security.KeyStoreKeyManager</class>
        <parameter name="keystore-location" value="/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/security/cacert" />
        <parameter name="keystore-password" value="password" />
        <parameter name="key-alias" value="{58e98c0f-d08b-48ca-925a-316e6fef24d9}" />
        <parameter name="key-password" value="password" />
        <parameter name="keystore-type" value="JKS"/>
        <parameter name="keystore-provider" value="org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider" />
</component>
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 with a Java version of

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

Here is a 'keytool -list' of the 'cacert' file

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

onrampserver_cert, 14-Oct-2015, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 2D:92:7C:26:29:BB:F5:2E:07:AC:58:C2:31:6F:B1:BB

{58e98c0f-d08b-48ca-925a-316e6fef24d9}, 14-Oct-2015, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 62:C4:C8:CC:38:57:FB:8D:EC:21:AF:46:9E:C7:6E:3F

northsideg2ca, 14-Oct-2015, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): F2:65:1D:C7:0D:54:55:54:F1:16:6F:DD:45:47:5B:60
```

Comment: What about using the default or Sun provider, instead of BouncyCastle ?